# Java calling a method with object parameters to main method

Tags: java, object, parameters, call

```
play.java: https://pastebin.com/4bzfE76z
values.java: https://pastebin.com/6mnUzKyA
player.java: https://pastebin.com/qiFymMF6
stats.java: https://pastebin.com/P24AUpXV
```

I have a method called **start** in *play.java* with object parameters. The objects were originally declared in *values.java* inside the **sValues** method. I want to call the method **start** to the **main method** of *play.java* but I'm not sure what to write inside the parameters of the call.

Inside *values.java*:

```
    player user = new player ();
    user.setP_Name (username);
    user.setP_ATK (atk);
    user.setP_HP (hp);

    stats[] enemies = new stats [3];
    enemies [1] = new stats ();
    enemies [1] = gob;
    enemies [1].getName ();
    enemies [1].getHP ();
    enemies [1].getATK ();
    enemies [1].getMANA ();
    enemies [2] = new stats ();
    enemies [2] = orc;
    enemies [2].getName ();
    enemies [2].getHP ();
    enemies [2].getATK ();
    enemies [2].getMANA ();
```

Inside `play.java`, I use the objects like this:

```
System.out.println ("Hitpoints[HP]: " + enemies [i].getHP ());
```

and it works great because I included these two objects into the parameter of the method:

```
public static void start (player user, stats[] enemies)
```

However, whenever I want to call **start** in the **main method** for it to do the things I want it to, it gives me errors. This is how I've been trying to call it:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{ //main method
start(player, stats);
} //main method
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any help appreciated. I'll gladly add more information if needed. New to coding and not sure what specific details need to be provided.

**My errors:**

```
{ //main method
    player player = new player();
    start(player, stats);
} //main method
```

Error on: start(player, **stats**);
*Cannot find symbol. Symbol: variable stats. Location: class play.*

This error is given when I hover over "stats" when using netbeans.

Comment: What errors? Show a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 added clearer information to what my error is

Comment: I think you're confusing the need of a class vs fields in an object. Your error is clearly that `stats` variable does not exist. Does a `Player`  have its own `Stats`? If so, why are they separate parameter?

Comment: Please do you use pastebin, show all relevant code in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main method is the entry point of your program. You have not instantiated anything else yet so there are no objects to pass into your start method.

You might need to give us more of your code, but you might need to try something like this first - and I this is making a lot of assumptions about your code

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{ //main method
    Player player = new Player(); // This is an instance of your Player class
    // and initialize your stats array.
    Values v = new Values();
    start(player, stats);
} //main method
```

Also providing the error you are getting may help also.

**EDIT**

After reviewing your code I can see some problems. In your `Values` class you have the method `sValues` which creates the enemies as you said, however they `stats[]` that you created in that method only has the scope of that method, so when that method is finished, the enemies you created have now disappeared.

You also have a lot of static reference - this is bad practice and you need to remove as much as possible. To do this you can change something like

```
 Values.sValues();
```

to

```
 Values v = new Values(); // in the constructor call what you need to
 v.sValues();
```

You need to think about where you are going to store your enemies stats array. You could move it to the top of your `Values` class and add a getter for it then your code could look like this

*Values.java*

```
public class values {
    public static String clear = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    public static String username;
    public static int atk = 1;
    public static int hp = 10;

    private stats[] enemies;

 // .. your other code
public void sValues () // this method should not be static
{ //sValue method 
    // .. other code
    enemies = new stats [3];  // Remove the declaration at the start of this line
    // .. other code
}

public stats[] getEnemies()
{
    return enemies;
}
```

*Play.java*

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    // Create a player
    player player = new player("Steve", 10, 10);
    // Initialise your values
    Values v = new Values();
    // create the enemies (this could be done in your values constructor)
    v.sValues();
    // Start with these enemies
    start(player, v.getEnemies());
}
```

Comment: I provided all my code at the top of my original post. I'm not sure what to provide specifically so I pastebinned it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I decided to take the simple way and added all the code from values.java into the same method in play.java. However, I will use the help you provided to make my future projects better. One more question though, how would I call a non static method to main if it's not static? I suppose I'll research it later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you have to create an instance of values.java and then get the player and stats objects from there to pass on to the main method. where are player, stats being declared in the play.java class?

try:

```
{
  player player = new player();
  stats[] stats = new stats[5];

  start(player, stats);
} //main method
```

and initialize stats array with desired values

Comment: player and stats themselves are classes, full of constructors.

**edit:** you said I have to make an instance of values.java, what do you mean by that?

Comment: values.java initialializes de objects you want to pass to start method in the main method right? to create a new instance of values just call one of the constructors values v = new values(); then if values has a method to get the objects your start method should look like start(v.getUser(), v.getEnemies());

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a comment - please use the comments option for asking for more details questions about the post.

Comment: v would have the initial values for the game to start right? Creating a new instance with new values(), will initialize the objects you need for your main method...  the other way would be to initialize the array and the user inside the main method and pass those arguments to start method.

Comment: WHAT?? I tried what you posted in your edit before, but this time I tried it and there are no errors. It says my build failed to run when I try to start it though, so now I got another problem... Thanks for your help though!